# How do I make a scrollbar appear when the browser window is smaller?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, browser, scrollbar

I have researched this question throughout this site and online and can't seem to find a solution.  I have a very simple site that has a video player in the middle.

I can't seem to figure out how to make a scrollbar appear so that you can see all of the content when you open the site on an iPad or iPhone - or when you make the browser window smaller,

This is a big problem for the iPad because it means that viewers can't play the video player.  How do I fix this?

I keep thinking there is something in my CSS which is causing the problem. But perhaps it can be fixed using a simple line of javascript in the head of my document?

I've added the overflow: scroll; to my body tag already... to no avail.

Here is the CSS I am using that I would think fix the issue:

```
body {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #195f88;
    background-image: url(../images/subtle-pattern-10.jpg);
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: scroll!important;
}
```

Comment: Also, I can see the scrollbar track... but you still can't "scroll"  very strange!  I added a scroll bar to the div tag with the player, and the the bar appears, but still doesn't allow you to scroll.  I'm very frustrated.

Comment: If the iPad doesn't want to show scrollbars, you can't really force it - that's a decision of the browser. It provides an other interface to scroll content - by sliding.

Comment: okay but when I make my browser window smaller, the scrollbar still doesn't activate...

Comment: There has to be a space between the code 'overflow:scroll !important'

Comment: it still didn't make the scroll work.  :(  you can see the site here:http://www.realtorcontractor.info/

Comment: The iPad doesn't show a scrollbar, it's a bit weird, it ignores this overflow: scroll completely I think, but if the body is larger than the viewport the browser should automatically detect this and let the user scroll, if this isn't the case just make the page longer, add a couple of brakes or use a margin-bottom on the video player...

Comment: ...ok that is good to know.  in this case, it's the width that is causing the issue.  the screen won't slide left to allow a person to even click on the player or playlist to the right.

Comment: my recommendation in that case is put a div round the whole thing and add `padding-right:100px;` to the css of that div, this should definitely make the page scroll left

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first - This site's HTML code is written badly. Very badly.
How is it that the content area is placed inside the sidebar div?
Why is it positioned using a (very) large relative position declaration?
Why is the sidebar fixed in the first place?

I'm afraid no one (that I know of) could probably help you unless you heavily refactor your code. Problem is, your page, at the moment, has no dimensions - since everything is either floated or position fixed, nothing is within the "flow" of the page, thus technically you have nothing to display, as far as the browser can see.
Your luck is you don't have

```
#wrap { overflow: hidden; }
```

Try it - see what happens to demonstrate what I mean.